# Getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/internal/Locatable at com.tests

Tags: java, selenium

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/interactions/internal/Locatable at com.tests.

Am getting this error when creating a driver instance for chrome or remote webdriver also.

Comment: Add required jars.

Comment: Please paste your code

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error as one of jar file is missing in your build path.
From the error I could see that the 'Locatable' class is missing.

> This '**Locatable**' class is available in
>   '**org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal**' package inside
>   '**client-combined-3.6.0.jar**'

However,I would recommend you to reimport all selenium related jars to your project,to make sure you wont be getting any such dependency issues down the line.
1.You can download selenium for java client 3.6.0 from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ 
2.Make sure you added all jars from selenium directory to your build path.
3.Rerun your project.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

After updating to 3.6.0 with latest jar's its working .